# Huffman Code Decoder Encoder In Java Source Generation

Tags: java, performance, parsing, huffman-code

I want to create a fast Huffman Code decoder in Java and therefore thought about lookup tables. Since those tables consume memory and we use Java code to navigate and access the tables one can easily (or not) write a programm / method that expresses the same table.

The problem with that approach is, I dont know what is the best strategy. I know it is a lot about what fits in the cache and branch prediction. Also the switch case implementation meaning the actual ASM is beyond me. If I have a in memory lookup table (or a hierarchy of it) I will be able to simply jump in and out but I doupt that for my purposal that table would fit in the cache.

Since I actually walk a tree one could implement it as if else statements requireing a certain number of comparisms but for each comparism it would need additional binary operations.

So the following options exist:

- General Algorithm using in Memory lookup tables
- If/else representation of the decision tree
- If/else representation with small switch statements to find the correct group of symboles (same bit pattern length) (fewer if statements, might be more code).
- Switch statement representation of the code

Writing and benchmarking is quite tricky so any initial thoughts would be great.

One additional problem that comes into play is the order of bits. The most significant bit comes always first meaning it is stored in reverse order.

> If your tree is A = 0, B = 10, C = 11 to write BAC it would actually be 01 + 0 + 11 (plus means append).

So actually the code have to be written in reverse order. using if /else or switch approach for groups it would not be a problem since masking out the bits is simple and the reverse of bit is simply possible but it would lose the idea of getting the index within the group out of the mask since in reverse bit order add and remove have different meaning and also a simple lookup is not possible.

Reversing the bits is a costly operation (I use 4bit lookup tables) not outweighting the performance penality of binary operations.

But reversing the bits on the go is better suited for this and require four operations per bit (shifting up, Masking out, add and also shifting the input down). Since I read bits ahead all those operations will be done in registers so they might take only a few cycles.

This way I can use switch, sub and if to find the right symbol group and also to return those.

So finaly I need advices. Since my codes are global for language processing, they can be hardwired (ie be in source).

I wonder what the parser generators like ANTRL use to express those decisions. Since they also seam to switch or if/else based on the input symbole it would might give me a clue.

[Updates]

I found a simplification that avoids the reverse bit problem but still adds costs per group. So I end up in writing the bits in the order of the groups to traverse. So I will not need four modifications per bit but per group (different bit lengths).

For each group we have:
1. The value for the first element, the size (and therefore the value for the last element within that group.

Therefore for each group the algorithm looks like:
1. Read mbits and combine with the current read value.
2. Compare the value with the last value of that group is it smaller its within that group if not its outside.  -> read next
3. If it is inside the group aan array of values can be accessed or use a switch statement.

This is totally generic and can be used without loops making it efficient. Also if the group was detected, the bit length of the code is known and the bits can be consumed from source since the code looks far ahead (reading from stream).

[Update 2]

To access the actual value one could use a single big array of elements grouped by group. Since the propability reduces for group to group it is very likely that a significant part fits L2 or L1 cache speeding up access here.

Or one uses switch statements.

[Update 3]

Depending on the cases of a switch the compiler generates either a tableswitch or a lookup switch. The lookup switch has a complexity of O(log n) and stores key, jmp offset pairs which is not preferable. Therefore checking for groups is better suited for if/else.

The tableswitch itself uses only a table of jump offsets and it only takes substract, compare, access, jmp to reach the destination, than it must executes a return value on a constant.

Therefore a table access looks more promising. Also to avoid an unnecessary jump each group might contain the logic to access and return the group symbols table. Storing everything in a big table is promising since it might be int or short per symbole and my codes often do only have 1000 to 4000 symbols at most making it actually short.

I will check if 1 - pattern will give me the opportunity to store and access the masks in a better way allowing for binary searching the correct group instead of advancing in O(n) and might even avoid any shift operations at all during the processing.

Comment: A switch may result in a sequence of test-and-branch operations and thus may not have an advantage over cascaded if statements.

Comment: I don't quite see what you mean with "order of bits" and the following paragraphs. If you have (using your ABC code) 01011xxx in a byte, it might be decoded as ABC or CAB, never as BAC.

Comment: ANTLR compiles the grammar into if statements, testing for token categories as produced by the preceding lexer, where characters are accumulated according to regular expressions.

Comment: Are you sure about ANTLR? I tought it also works with switch statements.

Comment: https://github.com/linkedin/bowser/blob/master/bowser-core/src/main/java/com/linkedin/bowser/core/grammar/gen/NQLParser.java

Take a look they use switch statements but I dont know why.

Comment: Perhaps, yes, occasionally, bit see my 1st comment about switch being compiled into test-and-branch, i.e., if(! cond) then jump x.

Comment: Laune thats only true for a certain switch. There is a switch where switches from x to y and it will be an index in a jump table this is very fast.

Comment: You have ascertained that Java JIT code compilation does this? How? (Of course I know that you can code jump tables, best in assembly language. I have seen gcc compiled code for switch statements without jump tables.)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.10

Java has two kinds of switch op-codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was quite simple. I support almost all solutions now. One can test every symbol group (same bit length), use a lookup table (10bit + 10bit + 10bit (just tables of 10bit, symbolscount + 1 is the reference to those talbes)) and generating java (and if needed javascript but currently I use GWT to translate it).

I even use long reads and shift operations to reduce the access to binary information. This way the code gets more efficiently since I only support a maximum bit size (20bit (so a table of a table) which makes 2^20 symbols and therefore at most a million).

For the ordering I use a generator for the bit masks just using shift operations and no requirement of reversing bit orders or such.

The table lookups can also be expressed in Java storing the tables as arrays of arrays (its interesting how big the java files can be without compilers to complain)).

Also I found it interesting that since comparing is expressing an ordering (half order I guess) one can sort the symbols and instead of mapping the symbols mapping the comparison index. By comparing two index one can simply sort streams of codes without touching to much. By also storing the first or first two comparison index (16 or 32bit) one can efficiently sort and therefore binary sort compressed strings using the same Huffman code, which makes it ideal to compress strings in a certain language.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't make sense of most of what you wrote in your (long) question, but there is a simple approach.

We'll start with a single table.  Let's say your longest Huffman code is 15 bits.  (In fact, deflate limits the size of its Huffman codes to 15 bits.)  Then construct a table with 32768 entries, where each entry is the number of bits in the next code, and the symbol for that code.  For codes less than 15 bits, there is more than one entry in the table for the same code.  E.g. if the code is 10010110 (7 bits) for the symbol 'C', then all of the indexes of the table xxxxxxxx10010110 have the same thing.  Those entries all have {7, 'C'}.

Then you get 15 bits from the stream, and look up the next code in the table.  You remove the number of bits from that table entry, and use the resulting symbol.  Now you get as many bits from the stream as you need to have 15, and repeat.  So if you used 7 bits, then get 8 more to get back to 15 and look up the next code.

The next subtlety is that if your Huffman code changes often, you might end up spending more time filling up that large table for each new Huffman code than you spend actually decoding.  To avoid that, you can make a two-level table which has, say, a 9-bit lookup (512 entries) for the first portion of the code.  If the code is 9-bits or less, then you proceed as above.  That will be the most common case, since shorter codes are more frequent (that being the whole point of Huffman coding).  If the table entry says that there are 10 or more bits in the code (and you don't know yet how much more), then you consume the first nine bits and go to a second-level table for those initial nine bits pointed to by the entry in the first table, that has entries for the remaining six bits (64 entries).  That resolves the remainder of the code and so tells you how many more bits to consume and what the symbol is.  This approach can greatly reduce the time spent filling tables, and is very nearly as fast since short codes are more common.  This is the approach used by [inflate](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/inftrees.c) in [zlib](http://zlib.net/).

Comment: I am aiming for is speed and memory compactness. I want to use the same approach for the decoding / encoding for the client side (Java, JavaScript). Also the code tables are a bit more complicated. In fact I mix up three different codes and a word dictionary to get a decent compression factor on average based . So in the end I aim for a static decoder (the encoder is more primitve and not often used since the scenario on the server is mostly read only). So the encoder is already finished. Big lookup tables are not desired and out of reach since they would reduce performance.

Comment: With the current version with everything within code and all the updated optimization I can decompress around 100Million symbols per second where 50% of those symbols would be complete words. The compression is between 1:3 and 1:4 taking 16bit per character its 1:6 to 1:8 so it is worth it. Since the code words for strings are stable they even do fine as keys.

Comment: @MartinKersten:  I think Mark's approach is a pretty good one.  You can control the table size by deciding how many bits you pick off in each munch, and use secondary tables as needed to process the balance.  If 15 is too many than use 9 as Mark suggested or whatever number you think best.

Comment: And by the way its not a long question it is just a longer description for a more complex statement. And as you wrote to not understand most of what I wrote, I guess I failed.

Comment: I already have lookup tables of the size of 8 bits for dynamic codes. Compared with the source code's current optimized representation I am four times faster using source code when compared to lookup. Also it shares no strutures at all since I inline and the array access is read only I was managing around 350Million symbols per second with four threads for a 256 symbols 9 groups code. Dont ask what the lookup table approach performed even if it access only one main table (beside being 12bits). It was about 10 times slower.

Comment: For speed, you want "big" tables.  (They really aren't very big.) Since the codes are fixed, they are an excellent application for big tables, since those tables are only made once. How compact do you want your "memory compactness" to be? I can't imagine that a few 10's of K of tables would be an issue on anything but the very tiniest embedded 8-bit microprocessor. I do not understand why "big" lookup tables "reduce performance", what your approach is, or what you mean by "big".

Comment: My approach is using no memory (everything in code) or as I do it currently a simple table exactly the size of the number of symbols (which I abstracted to 0 to n since I use the code to decide types, lengthes, symbols and word index in a dictionary (thats why I switch between three different codes in general). Currently my language code has just between 1024 and 4096 symbols based on how many words the dictionary has. You see this fits level 1 cache and to detect the group I just process some bit operations and ifs. (I dont need a second table access to know the width of the code.

Comment: > I do not understand why "big" lookup tables "reduce performance". 

A typical server has 24 cores who usually share L1 and L2 caches. Since this is a bread and butter algorithm it is important that it is fast and sound. Also I use one table per language. We support currently 48 languages. So having everything in source code would be very good since it will best. I also do put the dictionary in source code so I wont manage anything at all. (English 35kb class file, in memory about 50kb). There is no way I can beat that with lookup tables and be four times (and more) slower it is also bad.

Comment: But you are right If I would not go for a fixed code but have dynamic I use a modified lookup table. But currently I work on a dynamic version of this using a small table for the groups access it and have the index. It is more compact and also I try to find a way to look ahead. Like getting the information not inside not inside inside inside not inside at once for a single bit operation. It is possible if you look only for every second group. If that works out I would be able to get the right group in O(log n) instead of n.

Comment: @MartinKersten: "Everything in code" suggests you are building a decision tree based on the Huffman code.  That seems pretty straightforward to construct, but I don't see how that will be "small".  For any vocabulary of K items,  your decision tree will have to have K leaves, each of which shifts the Huffman stream, picks up the corresponding symbol and then jumps to a common collection point.  Assume "pick up symbol" compiles to a machine instruction, and "jmp to common point" compiles to a machine instruction.

Comment: ...  On an x86, you'll need something like 12 bytes (SHL reg,b/MOV reg,K/JMP target)...but a K entry table might be 5 bytes (the symbol, and an 8 bit "shift distance".   So I'd expect the table implementation to be about half the size of the decistion tree.   Worse, the decision tree takes O(log K) time to decode entries, presumably smaller than that because Huffman trees are biased towards short paths. But the lookup table is unit time access.    So... where is your performance win coming from?

Comment: Almost right. I create a tree only to group the leafs according to their root distance (depth/level) of the tree. Than I use the groups to create the patterns. Since the group already groups together all symbols it only takes two or three groups to determine the symbol (usually it is about 60 to 75% hit rate since if there are many symbols as likely the group will be less but more members). Since I know the number of bits for each group this comes without an table access.

Comment: Also having the code for a group also results in having the index of the symbol within the index so I do all symbols of a group. I currently found even a working solution for testing all groups in two or three operations (and on two values) and use binary search to find the correct group.

Comment: Putting this within JavaSource and let it compile directly I guess I have the fastest solution possible. For my natural language code I have about 20 groups within 3 independent codes. Therefore I make on average 3 to 4 decisions before I know the group and than I do a single table access (table is 2KB in size and so should fit L1. Since I also read bytes in advance ... You know this speed is quite high now. And my Laptop is T410 and very old. And since the code is stable I can even use those Strings as keys in a compressed index.

Comment: Hardware is cheap but doing this for one week now storing six times the amount of strings in memory and four times in hardware was worth it. Here everything has to do with strings.